# Set color of Listview items in a specific repeating pattern

Tags: android, listview, loops, android-listview

I wanted to know how I may go about creating a loop for setting a specific background colour to each of my listview items in a reoccurring pattern. Say I have 10 items and 4 colours and I want the 10 items to be coloured in order of the pattern and for it to repeat, until the items are all coloured. Considering I have the following colours in an Integer Array:

```
int[] colours = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA};
```

Comment: Do you know the order prior to defining your array adapter? will that list change? if it changes, will it have to change the row's background?

Comment: Yes its a predefined order and no it wont have to change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I would implement a custom `Adapter` or a `ViewBinder` for this.

In case of an `Adapter`, for example `ArrayAdapter` you have to override the `getView` method

```
...
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    }

    view.setBackgroundColor(colors[position % colors.length]);

    return view;
}
....
```

Comment: I've tried all such cases, none kept the same repeated order.

Comment: Try again with the edited code. I tested it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have to be clear about two things:

1. This should go in the process of `getView()`
2. `getView()` renders your rows, but it doesn't sequentially. Performance depends very much on your layout implementation, but you cannot guarantee your rows will be rendered in order.

That said, I think there could be a way to do this:

- Prior to passing your data to your `ArrayAdapter`, define an extra variable in your `ArrayList`, you should use a class if you're not yet using it.
- Assign it the number of the background you want to set it. Ideally, this should be an `int` with the `Color.YOURCOLOR` you want to set it.
- Once processing within your `getView()` method, get that data for the row and simply call:

  ```
  YourClass item = (YourClass) getItem[position];
  convertView.setBackgroundColor(item.getMyColor());
  ```